# why below setValues doesn't set the value at first submit

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

Try to use setValues update the initialValues, but when I first time submit, it's the old value. Start from second time submit, it is the new value.Why and how to fix it?

```
    <template>
  <form @submit="onSubmit">
    <input name="email" v-model="email" />
  <!-- <span>{{ errors.email }}</span> -->
  <input name="password" v-model="password" type="password" />
  <!-- <span>{{ errors.password }}</span> -->
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
 
</template>

<script setup>
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate';
import { computed, reactive, ref, inject, onMounted  } from 'vue';


const { errors, setErrors, setFieldValue, handleSubmit  } = useForm({
  initialValues: {
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: 'p@$$w0rd',
  }
});

const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (values, actions) => {
  actions.setValues({
    email: '12134123',
    password: '1122200',
  });
  console.log(values);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have 2 issues here.
First, the `v-model` email and password don't link with the form. You can change it by

```
const {
  ...,
  values
  useFieldModel,
} = useForm({
  initialValues: {
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: 'p@$$w0rd',
  },
});

const email = useFieldModel('email');
const password = useFieldModel('password');
...
```

Second, the `values` that you use in `onSubmit` is basically the form values when the submit button is clicked. In your code, the `v-model` is not connected to the form, so even if you type anything in the input fields, it won't update the values with those changes. The values only receives the initial values specified in `initialValues`, which in this case is 'example@gmail.com' and 'p@$$w0rd'.

After that, when you call `actions.setValues` inside `onSubmit`, you are setting new values for the form. So when you click the submit button again, the values will contain the newly set values

`useForm` has expose a `values` object, you can use it to get latest values of the form. I have update my demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-v4-radio-mradfs?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: I test your demo, in the console. It still log the old value at first submit.

Comment: @Liang, sorry I have misinterpret the question, I have updated the answer